# How to remove line breaks from paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking for a way to remove linebreaks like how this site did it

http://removelinebreaks.net/

Any pointers would be a great help.

Basically:
Input:

```
xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx \n
xxxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxx \n
\n
xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx \n
xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxx\n
```

Output:

```
xxxx xxxxx xxxx xxx xxx xxx xxxxxx \n
\n
xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxx xxxx xxxxx
```

So no line breaks until paragraph ends, this happens when copying text from pdfs, that brings these extra newlines, while the paragraph haven't actually ended yet.

Have been playing around with regex, and css whitespace properties, but no solution have been reached yet.

Comment: What is your input and expected output? Also where is your initial code?

Comment: What do you mean by _"abnormal linebreaks"_? Also, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that's why people are downvoting your question. Nothing personal! You should always post what you've found when searching for a solution, what you've tried so far, and what is not working when you try it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1. Replace all double newline by 'something' (that you won't find in your data of course; so could be something like '~#' for instance...)
2. delete all newlines
3. replace that thing by newlines